# MySQL time difference between now() and updated time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My code looks like this

```
$checksql= "SELECT Body, ( NOW() - Updated ) as Age FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."amazoncache WHERE URL = '" . $keyurl . "' AND NOT( Body LIKE '%AccountLimitExceeded%') AND NOT( Body LIKE '%SignatureDoesNotMatch%') AND NOT( Body LIKE '%InvalidParameterValue%');";
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($checksql);

        if (count($result) > 0){
            if ($result[0]->Age <= 6001 && $result[0]->Body != ''){ //that would be 60 min 1 seconds on MYSQL value
                $pxml = GetXMLTree($result[0]->Body);
                return $pxml;
            }}
```

I would like to change value `6001` to `1 week`.  Can anyone tell me how to calculate the value for `1 week, 2 weeks and 1 month`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like this..

```
$var = 3601; // (60 * 60) + 1
$oneWeek = $var+strtotime("+1 week");
$twoWeek = $var+strtotime("+2 week");
$oneMonth = $var+strtotime("+1 month");
```

Am I in the ballpark?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and i'm sorry. I'm a mysql noob. So please be patience with me. I still don't understand something here.  My plugin author says `6001 would be 60 min 1 seconds on MYSQL value`. But your variable says 3601. And whats the deal with adding plus 1? I mean why not its just `3600`

Comment: @user1091558 Its easiest to work in seconds (i find) 60Min 1Sec = 60*60+1 so 3601, right? `strtotime()` takes a string and converts that to a number of seconds (1 week = 7*24*60*60)

Comment: Ok I understood. One last question. Please check the select statement in my code. So the `$result[0]->Age` would be `NOW() - Updated`. Updated is a column name in my table. I guess my plugin author used mysql time. But your code uses php time. So I really don't understand that part. I thought for 1 week I should replace `6001` with `06235959`. This is what I understood with [this mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).

Comment: Seconds are the same in any language